# grep exclude multiple strings

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

I am trying to see a log file using `tail -f` and want to exclude all lines containing the following strings:

`Nopaging the limit is` and `keyword to remove is`

I am able to exclude one string like this:

```
tail -f admin.log|grep -v "Nopaging the limit is"
```

But how do I exclude lines containing either of `string1` or `string2`?

Answer (score 159):

### Filtering out multiple lines with `grep`:

Put these lines in `filename.txt` to test:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

**`grep` command using `-E` flag with a pipe between tokens in a string:**

```
grep -Ev 'def|jkl' filename.txt
```

prints:

```
abc
ghi
```

**egrep using `-v` flag with pipe between tokens surrounded by parens:**

```
egrep -v '(def|jkl)' filename.txt
```

prints:

```
abc
ghi
```

**Or if stacking `-e` flags through `grep` parameters is okay (credit -> `@Frizlab`):**

```
grep -Fv -e def -e jkl filename.txt
```

prints:

```
abc
ghi
```

Comment: I'm surprised nobody talked about the `grep -v -e def -e jkl` method which IMHO is clearer…

Comment: Or even better: `grep -Fv -e def -e jkl` which is even faster!

Comment: With the -F flag, you can use newlines as delimiters instead of pipes. This allows the use of command output as the filter more easily, e.g.: `grep -vF $(pgrep myprocess)`

Answer (score 84):

```
grep -Fv -e 'Nopaging the limit is' -e 'keyword to remove is'
```

`-F` matches by literal strings (instead of regex)

`-v` inverts the match

`-e` allows for multiple search patterns (all literal and inverted)

Comment: This is the right answer: The only one that avoids both the multiple `grep -v` instances and the artificial requirement of a regex (lets the multiple strings be specified cleanly in separate arguments). Just imagine constructing that regex programmatically in a script for strings that could contain anything…

Comment: Actually none of these are right answers because when passing no keywords to exclude it will exclude everything instead of nothing.

Comment: Are the stacked `-e` patterns AND or OR?

Comment: @RonJohn `-e` is OR, which would be `A OR B`. However, since this is being inverted by `-v`, it is equivalent to `NOT(A OR B)`, which is `(NOT A) AND (NOT B)`.

Answer (score 51):

Another option is to create a exclude list, this is particulary usefull when you have a long list of things to exclude.

```
vi /root/scripts/exclude_list.txt
```

Now add what you would like to exclude

```
Nopaging the limit is
keyword to remove is
```

Now use grep to remove lines from your file log file and view information not excluded.

```
grep -v -f /root/scripts/exclude_list.txt /var/log/admin.log
```

Comment: I didn't realize you could use `-v` with `-f` (or that the latter even existed).

Comment: very very useful!

Comment: Note, that you don't have to create temporary file for the exclusion list. In bash you can use process substitution. This is handy if the exclusion list is kinda dynamic and you'd have to generate it before each use only to be used once: `grep -v -f <(gen_exclusions.sh) /var/log/admin.log`

Answer (score 24):

```
egrep -v "Nopaging the limit is|keyword to remove is"
```

Answer (score 17):

```
tail -f admin.log|grep -v -E '(Nopaging the limit is|keyword to remove is)'
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use regular grep like this:

`tail -f admin.log | grep -v "Nopaging the limit is\|keyword to remove is"`

Comment: This answer worked for me on MacOSX. Escaping the pipe is key

Answer (score 9):

The greps can be chained. For example:

```
tail -f admin.log | grep -v "Nopaging the limit is" | grep -v "keyword to remove is"
```

Comment: The catch here is that instead of process which would be filtering out, you'd have to run N processes sequentially, where each one of them filters something out. It could slow down things significantly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex:

`grep -Ev -e "^1" -e '^lt' -e 'John'`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer