# show only users you can log into

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to show user accounts but only those which I can log into. My code shows all users:

```
awk -F":" '{if ($NF!="/bin/nologin" && $NF!="/bin/false" ) {print $1}}' ./etc-passwd
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the issue? Did you inspect the file? Well, are you sure it's `/bin/nologin` not `/usr/bin/nologin"`. So print the output - do `printf $1, $NF` and check.

Comment: Do you mean `/etc/passwd` instead off `./etc-passwd`?

Comment: You're right. How to fix it to contains that string, not is that string?

Comment: It should be `/etc/passwd`? You can [edit] your question to change it.

Comment: You can log into any account; `/bin/nologin` and `/bin/false` are just examples of login "shells" that immediately exit *following* logging in.

Comment: Or put another way, the program listed in `/etc/passwd` is just the program (the default shell) executed on login. You can always bypass it. (The `login` command, for example, lets you specify a program to run other than the default shell.)

Answer (score 1):

We can use [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) to find each line which;

does **not** contain any of the following strings:

- `/nologin`
- `/bin/false`
- `/bin/sync`

```sh
grep -v -e '/nologin' -e '/bin/false' -e '/bin/sync' /etc/passwd
```

- [grep exclude multiple strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212656/grep-exclude-multiple-strings)

Comment: Might also want to exclude comments: `-e '^#'` and blank lines `-e '^[[:blank:]]*$'`

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```sh
awk -F: '$1 !~ /^#/ && $7 !~ /\/(false|nologin)$/' /etc/passwd
```

if the line does *not* start with a comment, **and** it does *not* end with a slash followed by "false" or "nologin", then print it.